# iOS swift post method with return string

Tags: ios, swift, post

how do i write post method with return fetched string

```
func post(link:String,passedPostString:String) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: link)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    request.httpBody = passedPostString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            print("******Error*****")
            return

        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

      print(responseString!)




    }
    task.resume()
}
```

then i call it something like

```
var link  = "link"
var passedPostString = "passedPostString"
print(post(link: link , passedPostString: passedPostString ))
```

which will return the fetched value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function that makes an async network call cannot have a return type as it may take a while before completing. You would not want you system to freeze and wait until the response, that would beat the purpose.

You can instead add new parameter with a completion closure that will be called when the request finishes like this:

```
func post(link:String,passedPostString:String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: link)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = passedPostString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        // Make sure there is no error, else..
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        completion(responseString, nil)

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Brilliant as always , thanks for the fast reply @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The `dataTask` method is asynchronous, so there is no way to come back with an immediate return value, as you have no idea when this will be called.

Your best bet is to pass in a completion handler that will be called asynchronously from your main code:

```
func post(link:String, passedPostString:String, completionHandler: @escaping (NSString) -> ()) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: link)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    request.httpBody = passedPostString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            print("******Error*****")
            return

        }
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        completionHandler (responseString!);
    }
    task.resume()
}


var link  = "link"
var passedPostString = "passedPostString"
let completion = { (result: NSString) in print(result) }
post(link: link, passedPostString: passedPostString, completionHandler: completion)
```